Linkedin oauth error Not enough permissions to access: me
I have seen a lot of posts about this, but all of them are pretty outdated.
I am creating a symfony application wiht oauth, and trying to implement linkedin login.The scopes I use are: email,profile, and with these scopes I got this error: Not enough permissions to access: me.GET.NO_VERSION
If I use these scopes:r_liteprofile, r_emailaddress I get an error that says that these scopes are not authorized for your application
Some says that are need premission from linkedin, some says that it should work. So where are they stand with this now?
How can I fix this?
Thank You all in advance!

If you're using OpenID Connect (Considering your scopes are profile, email), you should use the endpoint /userInfo.
To access /me, you need the r_basicprofile permission (not r_liteprofile, which is deprecated).
For more details, refer to the official LinkedIn documentation:

Retrieve current member's profile
Sign in with LinkedIn - Authenticating members

Good luck!
